# Enhanced debug information for discriminated unions

Tags: f#

From what I can gather, the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` cannot be applied to individual levels of a discriminated union, only to the top-level class.

The corresponding [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2022) suggests that overriding the `ToString()` method is an alternative way.

Taking the following example:

```
type Target =
    | Output of int
    | Bot of int

    override this.ToString () =
        match this with
        | Output idx -> $"output #{idx}"
        | Bot idx -> $"bot #{idx}"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =    
    let test = Bot 15
    
    0
```

When breaking on the return from `main` and placing a watch on `test`, the VS2019 debugger is showing `Bot 15` rather than `bot #15`.

The documentation also suggests that:

> Whether the debugger evaluates this implicit ToString() call depends
> on a user setting in the Tools / Options / Debugging dialog box.

I cannot figure out what user setting it is referring to.

**Is this not available in VS2019 or am I just missing the point?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem here is that the F# compiler silently emits a `DebuggerDisplay` attribute to override the default behavior described in the documentation you're looking at. So overriding `ToString` alone is not going to change what the debugger displays when debugging an F# program.

F# uses this attribute to implement its own plain text formatting. You can control this format by using [`StructuredFormatDisplay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/plaintext-formatting#customize-plain-text-formatting-with-structuredformatdisplay) to call `ToString` instead:

```ml
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{DisplayString}")>]
type Target =
    | Output of int
    | Bot of int

    override this.ToString () =
        match this with
        | Output idx -> $"output #{idx}"
        | Bot idx -> $"bot #{idx}"

    member this.DisplayString = this.ToString()
```

If you do this, the Visual Studio debugger will display `"bot #15"`, as you desire.

Another option is to explicitly use `DebuggerDisplay` yourself at the top level, as you mentioned:

```ml
[<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")>]
type Target =
    | Output of int
    | Bot of int

    override this.ToString () =
        match this with
        | Output idx -> $"output #{idx}"
        | Bot idx -> $"bot #{idx}"
```

FWIW, I think the direct answer to your question about the Tools / Options / Debugging setting is "Show raw structure of objects in variables windows". However, this setting isn't really relevant to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks @brianberns... Not only for clarifying the required option but for the workaround as well. I had no idea about the silent emitting of `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`. I also hadn't realised there was a `StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute` which influences the `%A` format pattern under `printfn`.